# How to let user toggle between front facing and rear camera in UIImagePicker?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How to let user toggle between front facing and rear camera in UIImagePicker?

```
-(void)takePhoto {
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
#else
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
#endif
imagePickerController.editing = YES;
imagePickerController.delegate = (id)self;
[self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

can't be told enough. When writing code in Xcode you can right-click on any class, enum, method etc. to browse to the definition and read on.
So when you right-click on `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` and "Jump to Definition" you will end up reading UIKit/UIImagePickerController.h

Protocol `<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>` knows of an Enum with name `UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice` that has two entrys, `UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear` or  `UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront`

and later on the protocol tells, you have a

```
@property(nonatomic) UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice cameraDevice;
```

available.

Meaning, you can set

```
imagePickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
```

and also defined in the protocol which your imagePickerController is following

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL showsCameraControls;
```

so you can

```
imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = YES;
```

makes it easy for you and the users know how to handle that interface.

Comment: @Ol_Sen, have you seen my answer? The OP want the user to be able to **toggle** between cameras, not just force it to one - and it appears to be a feature of `UIImagePickerController`.

Answer (score 1):

More than happy to delete this if necessary, just trying to help....

I just tried my Swift-written app that uses `UIImagePickerController`, with this code that I haven';t touched since 2016. It looks similar to your code - except that `allowsEditing = false`, which to you means `editing = NO`. (I also check for a rear-facing camera to make sure it's not a simulator running the code.) To me, it looks like `UIImagePickerController` *automatically* gives the user a way to switch to the front-facing camera.

```
    if UIImagePickerController.availableCaptureModes(for: .rear) != nil {
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera
        picker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
        picker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(picker,
                animated: true,
                completion: nil)
    } else {
        noCamera()
    }
}
```

Have you tried setting editing to NO?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I just tried setting it to `NO` with the same result. Update in progress

Comment: @McMonty, what device are you testing on? iPhone or iPad? The devices I have are iPhone SE original, iPad Mini, and iPro 12.9. On both iPads I see the toggle button above the take snapshot button on the right. On the iPhone the controls are fixed, in portrait they are at the bottom and the toggle is on the bottom right. By "fixed" I mean that in landscape the controls move depending on landscape left or landscape right.

Comment: iPad Mini iOS 9.3.5

Comment: Ah. That was my original target back in 2016, but now my iPads are on iOS 14 beta 3 - my next app is targeting that. Good luck!